# Android Management API for private use?

Tags: android-management-api

Have I got this right?

We want to build an in-house kiosk management solution that would deploy > 50 devices, and [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/introduction) seems to fit the bill. The issue is, I can't make sense of the documentation. Everything seems aimed at making a publicly available product- like an EMM vendor listed in a marketplace.

1. The development [usage limits are low](https://developers.google.com/android/management/usage). To raise them, you are forced to join the [EMM program](https://developers.google.com/android/management/join).

> Before you can increase your usage limits and release a production
>   EMM solution, you need to join Google's EMM Community.

2. Once you join the EMM program, it looks like you have 180 days to release a solution to 'production', or you are [kicked out of the program](https://developers.google.com/android/work/release-solution#3_pass_product_review).

> If an EMM fails to pass product review within 180 days of joining the
>   EMM community, access to Android's Enterprise's services will be
>   revoked. Access may also be revoked if an EMM attempts to use Androids
>   Enterprise's services in a production environment before passing a
>   product review.

[This page](https://developers.google.com/android/work/release-solution) goes on to say:

> All Android EMM solutions made publicly available must support a minimum set of features.

Does this mean there are private apps?

> Key Point: EMM solutions that pass product review are listed in the Android Business Partners directory.

This suggests if you cannot be private, you must be public, and you will be listed. Which essentially means this API is for business partners, not general availability.

Answer (score 1):

The default usage limits have now been increased to 1,000 devices and 1,000 requests per 100 seconds, which should be more than enough for your needs.

If you need to go above these limits, just join the EMM Community and ask for your quota to be increased. If your use case is legitimate Google will increase your quota. Use cases are reviewed on a case by case basis, and Google may also ask that you support some features.